# Spring отображение статических элементов

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-boot

Приложение собираю при помощи @SpringBootApplication, стили получилось подключить в файле index.jsp

```
<style>
        <%@include file='../css/main.css' %>
</style>
```

Однако вывести изображение никак не получается, при попытке обратиться к картинке через адресную строку http://localhost:8080/img/gmail.png, выводиться сообщение в консоле браузера, что изображение не найдено
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте переложить картинки в папку `webapp/static/img` или `resources/static/img`.

Comment: Пробовал и оба варианта, не помогает

Comment: @АндрейМаврин Странно. Странно, здесь все работает: https://start.spring.io/#!type=gradle-project&language=java&platformVersion=2.2.1.RELEASE&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=1.8&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=web

Comment: @АндрейМаврин можете дать ссылку на исходники?

Comment: https://github.com/pimmpo/BMOproject_springboot только что попробовал через spring start не выходит

Comment: @АндрейМаврин а у вас репозиторий не приватный случаайно? Получаю 404 при переходе.

Comment: спасибо за заинтересованность, проблему решил, поэтому скрыл его, проблема была в том, что intelliJ почему-то не видел путь до статических элементов, я самостоятельно в настройках проекта указал ему директорию и всё заработало, большое спасибо еще раз! :)